# Composite map: take data from another Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I need to take the occurrences of words taken from a file, using `map<string,int>`, and then I need to copy them to a `map<int,
vector<string>, cmpDec >`, and print them in decreasing order.

I tried to take word frequencies from a file to a `map<string, int>` and then I'm trying to copy it to a `map<int,
vector<string> >` with no results

I have declared 2 maps:

```
map<string, int> text;
map<int, vector<string>, cmpDec> freq;
```

I take the text from a file in the first map with the word frequencies:

```
while (rf >> words) {
    text[words]++;
}
```

Now I have to put the frequencies in the second map (required), where I need to have first `int`, for num of word frequencies, `vector` with the words for each freq, and the compare for decreasing frequencies.
Now i'm trying to put the datas in the second map from the first in these ways:

```
map<string, int>::iterator iter_map1 = text.begin();
map<int, vector<string>>::iterator iter = freq.begin();
vector<string>::iterator iter_v;
for (; iter_map1 != text.end(); ++iter_map1) {
   iter->first.insert(make_pair(iter_map1->second, iter->second.push_back(iter_map1->first)));
}
```

It gives 2 errors on the iter->second.... line:

```
...\BagOfWords.cpp|56|error: request for member 'insert' in 'iter.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator-><std::pair<const int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >()->std::pair<const int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first', which is of non-class type 'const int'|
```

and

...\BagOfWords.cpp|56|error: invalid use of void expression|

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to take words (and their frequencies) from a file and put them on the second map without passing from the first?

Comment: what's wrong with just inserting them using `freq[cnt]`?

Answer (score 2):

With `C++17` you can do *[structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)*, which helps a lot when iterating through a `map`.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using WordCounts       = std::map<std::string, int>;
using FrequencyOfWords = std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>, std::greater<int>>;

int main()
{
    WordCounts word_counts;
    FrequencyOfWords words_freq;
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"test", "hello", "test", "hello", "word"};

    for(const auto& word : words)
        word_counts[word]++;

    for(const auto& [word, count] : word_counts)
        words_freq[count].push_back(word);

    for (const auto& [freq, words] : words_freq)
    {
        std::cout << "freq " << freq << " words";
        for (auto const& word: words)
            std::cout << " " << word;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do this in one pass as you don't know the word counts upfront.

First, a couple of recommendations. Use `typedef` (or `using` for C++ 11 or later). This will save you some typing and also ensure that your types are correct. In your code `freq` and `iter` don't have the same underlying container type (they differ in the comparison used).

Secondly, try to use the standard library as much as possible. You don't show `cmpDec` but I guess that it is a comparator based on greater-than rather than the default less-than. I would prefer to see `std::greater<int>` rather than a custom comparator.

For your errors, in the line

```
iter->first.insert(...
```

`iter` is at the start of `freq` and you are trying to insert to `first` which is `int`.

This should probably be something like

```
freq[iter_map1->second].push_back(iter_map1->first);
```

Breaking that down

- `freq[iter_map1->second]` This uses the `int` word count from `text` to lookup an entry in `freq`. If there is no entry an empty one will be inserted to `freq`.
- `.push_back(iter_map1->first)` This inserts the `string` from `text` to the `vector` that was found or created in the previous step

Here is a full example of what I think you are trying to achieve.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::map;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::greater;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;

using WordCounts = map<string, int>;
using FrequencyOfWords = map<int, vector<string>, greater<int>>;

int main()
{
    WordCounts text;
    FrequencyOfWords freq;

    ifstream rf("so26.cpp");

    string words;
    while (rf >> words)
    {
        text[words]++;
    }

    WordCounts::const_iterator iter_map1 = text.begin();
    for (; iter_map1 != text.end(); ++iter_map1)
    {
        freq[iter_map1->second].push_back(iter_map1->first);
    }

    for (auto const& e: freq)
    {
        cout << "freq " << e.first << " words";
        for (auto const& w: e.second)
        {
            cout << " " << w;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that way, but the compiler gives error "no match for operator[]"

Comment: Even better, instead of `typedef` or `using`, use `auto`. For example `auto iter_map1 = text.begin();`.

Comment: You declared the variable `iter_v` but you never use it.

Comment: I've removed iter_v (it wasfrom the OP's code). I wanted to make the point about typedef/auto, otherwise I would recommend auto.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but I reckon the following does what you want (I prefer unordered maps, as they are faster and you don't seem to need the ordering)

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,int> word_counts;
std::string word;
while(input >> word)
    word_counts[word]++;

std::unordered_map<int,std::vector<std::string>> words_by_freq;
for(const auto& counted : word_counts)
    words_by_freq[counted::second].push_back(counted::first);
```